# How to create large tile in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535, tiles, pin-to-start, personalization

For PC's We can create tiles of four sizes wiz. small, medium, wide and large. But for my Lumia 535 running Windows 10 Mobile it seems that only first three could be pinned. Tapping on resizing button of wide tile resize it back to small. I have even tried in continuum mode but the large tile cannot be pinned. Is this because I have a low-resolution device (540x960) or Windows 10 Mobile does not allow to pin large tiles? Non-official workarounds are also appreciated as my phone is interop-unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

This feature used to be in some of the preview builds but Microsoft pulled it out, citing issues with Start screen layouts. They said it would be quite some time before it was put back in, and given the current rate of development I wouldn't expect to see it any time soon, if ever.

Comment: Hmmm...Perhaps you're right :(

Answer (score 1):

For now, even on the latest release build (10.0.14393.693), it is not possible to have a large tile.

Try searching for such an feedback in the Feedback Hub about having a large tile option and upvote it your create our new one. Hopefully, this feature might roll out in the next OS updates, so be ready to install them.

Hope this helps. If it did, give me an upvote.